# How to import photos from a digital camera using USB OTG?

Tags: camera, photos, usb-on-the-go, import

I have some simple digital camera for my kids with only internal memory. I do have some windows software for it to import the photos. The windows software looks a bit outdated, but it works.

When I connected it on an Ubuntu machine to read the USB ID ("ID 0979:0227 Jeilin Technology Corp., Ltd JL2005B/C/D Toy Camera") it worked instantly. The memory was mounted as a drive, I could see the photos and copy them!

But when I go on holiday I will have neither a Windows PC nor an Ubuntu machine nearby. I will only have my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, which supports USB OTG.

When I connect the camera via the USB OTG connector, the camera gives a bleep and on my tablet I see a message "USB connector attached". But I don't see a mounted drive (which I do see when I connect a simple USB memory stick).

Is there some kind of app to import the photos from a digital camera?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The camera may be connecting on PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol) or MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) mode, not as a normal USB drive (which uses USB Mass Storage drivers). It shows up in Ubuntu similarly to a USB Mass Storage device, but Android has no support for this out of the box.

You could try an app that supports PTP, such as [DslrDashboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dslr.dashboard&hl=fi), but I haven't tried these personally, so no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The camera is a very simply thing, produced probably during the Windows XP era. Do you think it will support PTP or MTP then?

Comment: Sorry, no luck. I cannot see the camera with DslrDashboard.

Comment: @onik: AFAIK, MTP and PTP are available when Android becomes slave and PC becomes host. In ffonz's question, Android is the host and camera is the slave, so I don't understand how come PTP and MTP would be available other than OTG USB Storage mount. Care to explain.

Comment: @Firelord If the camera itself supports only MTP or PTP slave mode, it needs a host that can act as a MTP/PTP master. I don't mean the USB connection mode in Android settings, but an app that emulates a MTP/PTP master.